# C# Getting user mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid in Decimal format

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to get the value of an attribute in its decimal form, but have consistently come up with blank values.

In Active Directory, when opening the mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid attribute, it opens an "Octet String Attribute Editor". In this editor it allows you to choose Decimal format (this is the exact format I'm trying to get the string in my GUI to display as.

This is my current code, which works fine for getting attributes/properties such as distinguishedName, userPrincipleName etc, but it returns a blank value.

An example (not real) value is: **026 084 028 230 104 168 129 035 136 021 197 072 054 129 001 167**

Any assistance is appreciated!!

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, mydomain))        
{
    using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, UserID))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
           cguid = ((DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject()).Properties["mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid"].Value as String;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all GUID values coming from AD (like `objectGuid` too), it is presented as a byte array. You can use that byte array to create a [`Guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor#System_Guid__ctor_System_Byte___) object, then do whatever you'd like with it:

```
var de = ((DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject());

var consistencyGuid = new Guid((byte[]) de.Properties["mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid"].Value);

cguid = consistencyGuid.ToString();
```

Comment: I've tried this, but when I convert the value to the same format (as above), whilst the format is correct, the value is not.

Comment: var guidBytes = string.Format("0{0:N}", value);
var bigInteger = BigInteger.Parse(guidBytes, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var bigString = bigInteger.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
bigString = bigString.Replace(',', ' ');
return bigString;

Comment: If you want the Guid presented in a specific format, you can use my code and then use one of the format specifiers supported in [`.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring#System_Guid_ToString_System_String_)

Comment: The format is correct, just the value the above retrieves is different from the below.

We have another utility that gets this value in PowerShell via
$currUser = Get-ADUser $username -property * -server $domain | Select *

then further along:
$AttributeDisp.Items.Add("consistencyGUID: " + $currUser."mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid"

Comment: That just shows every byte in the array rather than showing you the string representation of the GUID. If you want to see every byte in the array, just loop through `(byte[]) de.Properties["mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid"].Value`. However that format is rarely ever used. The normal string representation is the hex values of those bytes. You can read more about it in the Wikipedia page for UUID: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format

Comment: Perfect, tried so many things prior to this, tried it before but my original code was wrong. Thankyou, all as expected!!